# Targeting a Circle Element with CSS

Tags: css, elementor

I am trying to target the "Ingredient Quality" progress circle (an Elementor element) on this page with CSS: https://dogfoodreviews.wpengine.com/?p=7

I can't seem to figure out the CSS Selector. I noticed in the HTML that the color of the circle is housed in a  HTML element. It's the "Stroke" color below.

Can I change this with CSS? I am using a dynamic class that I need to change the color based on the class.

```
<circle
    class="circle-progress__value"
    cx="79.5"
    cy="79.5"
    r="66"
    stroke="#7C9579"
    stroke-width="27"
    data-value="70"
    style="stroke-dasharray: 414.690230274; stroke-dashoffset: 414.690230274;"
    fill="none"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, you can change svg element stroke color via css. For your case you made need to get very target specific or use `!important` to override the current css

Comment: I was able to use the "stroke" element. I didn't realize that was a CSS element.

Thanks!